# How to color just the text in parentheses

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF (C#) Application, I want to color just the text in parentheses. Any help?
**Ex:**
In this text:
The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', sometimes on purpose **(injected humour and the like)**.

...the `(injected humour and the like)` must be colored in red.

**Actually, I use RichTextBox to display the text..**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using multiple `Run` elements inside a `TextBlock` control. The text will still flow within the bounds of the TextBlock. For example ...

```
<TextBlock MaxWidth="100" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text="Standard Text " />
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="red text" />
    <Run Text=" more standard text." />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Not actually what I need, I have dynamic text returned from Database, and programtically I have to color the text in parentheses.